# Outliner issue - expanding manually

Tags: outliner

I appear to have lost the ability to expand Outliner hierarchies manually.

I am able to expand and collapse with +/- but it expands everything visible collapsed and collapsing collapses everything.

I used to be able to click on the +/- bubbles to open/close the specific item I want but this is where my problem lies. I can't. At least not anymore, which is what I need because my projects contain a lot of seperate objects at times and expanding everything is hella messy.

I'm not sure if this is an issue caused by version, a script, or a hotkey/preference I may have selected to cause this inability. Was hoping someone might know so I don't have to reinstall everything to fix the problem.

I also can't select items on outliner with left click either. Which maybe the source of the issue.

Comment: Which version?  Try _`File > Load Factory Settings`_? Which may determine if it's an addon or faulty keymap if it works correctly after.

Answer (score 0):

You can restore the default key maps if you go to User Preferences(<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>), Input tab and choose Restore for the Outliner:

[image]

You may have conflicting settings in other key maps as well. You could also try searching for everything assigned to mouse buttons.

If all fails, you could restore all key maps to default. If that fails, there might be an add-on that is causing the trouble, you would need to disable all enabled add-ons one by one to find the one causing issues.

You could rename or delete(maybe backup first) `%appdata%\Blender Foundation\Blender\[your version]` (on Windows) folder to restore everything to default, but that would disable all installed add-ons as well as your UI color theme.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to be the issue. Took a look and there isn't a restore so I didn't change any keymaps to have caused this problem.

Comment: I updated my answer.